# Material 3 TimePicker in Jetpack Compose

Tags: timepicker, android-jetpack-compose-material3

When will Material 3 TimePicker be available in Jetpack Compose

I cannot go ahead and test anything, because it is unavalable. I have migrated to Material 3 and it seems it is the only component in my project not available. The waiting period will inform my decision to roll back or be patient as I furnish the other functionalities.

Comment: Welcome to SO ! You should consider asking directly to JetPack Compose because their staff members may be not present on this site.